# Difference between ( view.$el and $(view.el)) in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
view.$el and $(view.el)
```

can you tell me what is the difference between     `view.$el` and `$(view.el)` .I follow some web sites but I couldn't find elaborate answer.It would be very helpful if solve t difference because I am new to bacbone.

Comment: [`view.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el): A cached jQuery object for the view's element. A handy reference instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time.

Comment: re-wrapping the DOM element  what do u mean by that

Answer (score 1):

Trace the source code of Backbone.View might help you figure out the difference between $(view.el) and view.$el. setElement function will be invoked when you create a new instance of Backbone View.

```
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
  if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
  this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
  this.el = this.$el[0];
  if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
},
```

Backbone will convert DOM or selector string to jQuery object (if needed) and assign it to this.$el here.

```
this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
```

Then assign the DOM element to this.el

```
this.el = this.$el[0];
```

jQuery programmer usually define a jquery object variable which starting with a dollar sign. It brings some benefits:

1. Easy to identify (we can't call find() on DOM element)
2. Performance improvment:
   We always create a jQuery object variable when we want to cache the jquery selecting result (avoid re-selecting in DOM tree or re-wrapping the DOM). Re-selecting or re-wrapping DOM might cause performance issue. Especially you have a huge and complex DOM structure.

---

```
//re-selecting
$("#test").click(function(){
  //event hanlder
});
$("#test").addClass("viewed");

//re-wrapping
var dom = getElementById("test");
$(dom).find(".anchor").removeClass("viewed");
$(dom).click(function(){
   //event hanlder
});
```

So... what difference between view.$el and $(view.el)? $(view.el) just re-wrap view's DOM element again and I think you could use view.$el directly.

Comment: hey thank u for reply can you explain re-selecting in DOM tree or re-wrapping the DOM)

Answer (score 1):

[Chickenrice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23193587/1104483) has already answered on your question but I would like to add my 50 cents.

I would suggest avoiding `$(whatever)` and use `view.$(whatever)` instead. This approach will help avoiding conflicts between views.

- `$(whatever)` - Search through the `document` elements so you can modify an element outside the view by mistake
- `view.$(whatever)` - Search inside current view

Answer (score 0):

They're functionally the same. The first one is better since you don't need to wrap it in jQuery object each time.

[http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el)

Comment: can you expalin litllr bit more

Comment: DOM manipulations usually done with jQuery thus `view.$el` exists just for programmer's convenience (and a little optimization).